# Image sequence starts animating before it's in view

Tags: javascript, html, scrolltop

I'm trying to replicate apple's image sequencing animation - https://www.apple.com/airpods-pro/. I've managed to track down a few examples and they all work great but they all trigger at the top of the page and I want mine to trigger in the middle of the page. I've tried attaching the trigger event to the #graphHolder container but it still starts cycling through the images as soon as you scroll at the top of the page. Can anyone point to where I'm going wrong? Here's a jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/mvyw2bc3/2/

```
const html = document.documentElement;
const canvas = document.getElementById("hero-lightpass");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

const frameCount = 132;
const currentFrame = index => ( `https://res.cloudinary.com/icebreakernz/image/upload/v1623273037/globalcampaign/plastic-free/sequence-test/IB-Graph_Animation${index.toString().padStart(4, '0')}.jpg`
)

const preloadImages = () => {
  for (let i = 1; i < frameCount; i++) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = currentFrame(i);
  }
};

const img = new Image()
img.src = currentFrame(1);
canvas.width=1920;
canvas.height=1080;
img.onload=function(){
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

const updateImage = index => {
  img.src = currentFrame(index);
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {  
  const scrollTop = html.scrollTop;
  const maxScrollTop = html.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
  const scrollFraction = scrollTop / maxScrollTop;
  const frameIndex = Math.min(
    frameCount - 1,
    Math.ceil(scrollFraction * frameCount)
  );
  
  requestAnimationFrame(() => updateImage(frameIndex + 1))
});

preloadImages()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that runs in to the same problem, I ended up going with [ScrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/) which made it super simple. Check out my fiddle here to see it working as it should - https://jsfiddle.net/jdrebugL/

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("hero-lightpass");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = 1920;
canvas.height = 1080;

const frameCount = 132;
const currentFrame = index => ( `https://res.cloudinary.com/icebreakernz/image/upload/v1623273037/globalcampaign/plastic-free/sequence-test/IB-Graph_Animation${(index + 1).toString().padStart(4, '0')}.jpg`
);

const images = []
const airpods = {
  frame: 0
};

for (let i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = currentFrame(i);
  images.push(img);
}

gsap.to(airpods, {
  frame: frameCount - 1,
  snap: "frame",
  scrollTrigger: {
    scrub: 1,
    trigger: "#hero-lightpass",
    start: "top top",
    pin: true
  },
  onUpdate: render // use animation onUpdate instead of scrollTrigger's onUpdate
});

images[0].onload = render;

function render() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.drawImage(images[airpods.frame], 0, 0); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can't you maybe make an intersection observer and make it trigger on a div that is pushed to the bottom of the image (maybe with a position absolute and bottom zero or you know whatever) and then trigger whatever callback function within the observer ? i'm not sure this is of any help but here is a function i made that lets you call a callback function when an element is intersecting

```
export const elementObserver = (callback, options) => {
 if (typeof options.element != "undefined") {
   return new IntersectionObserver(
     (entries, observer) => {
       entries.forEach(entry => {
         let target = entry.target;
         if (entry.isIntersecting) {
           callback(options);
         }
       });
     },
     {
       threshold: 0.5
     }
   ).observe(options.element);
 }
}
```

you need to pass all of the callback function variables within a javascript map and the map has to have a key called 'element' for it to work (element is the element to be watching for intersection) ... also in it's current state it's written in es6 but you can easily translate that.
oh and play with the threshold maybe but it to 1 to further delay the action

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I ended up going with gsaps scrollTrigger in the end. Was a really elegant solution.

Comment: great! glad you found a good solution. the plugin you mentioned sounds great but if you're going this route you should probably consider tree shaking because the plugin probably does a lot more than what you need, and you don't want all of that extra js slowing you down.

Comment: Yeah for sure, thankfully my design has a lot of elements animating in as you scroll through the rest of the page so it's perfect for what I need. I was initially using scrollmagic but have subbed that out in favour of this otherwise if it was a one off I would have gone with a slimmed down version as you said.